# Adding data to spinner

Tags: java, android, file, spinner, adapter

Hey so I'm building a mini app for uni which basically loads a spinner with pre existing data and the user can also add data to the file through multiple fields. When the user fills in the fields and clicks the button, I add it to the data to its relevant array lists.

Now I confused when I add it to the names array which is the array thats fills the spinner, why it automatically adds to the spinner, without me calling an `adapter` method such as `adapter.add(nametxt.getText().toString())`.

```
public void addinglocations(View view){
    String filename = "au_locations.txt";

//add the edittext fields to the arrays lists
    names.add(nametxt.getText().toString());
    lats.add(Double.parseDouble(lattxt.getText().toString()));
    longs.add(Double.parseDouble(longtxt.getText().toString()));
    timezone.add(tztxt.getText().toString());

//writing to file
    String fileContents = nametxt.getText().toString() + "," + lattxt.getText().toString() + "," + longtxt.getText().toString() + "," +  tztxt.getText().toString() + "\r\n";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add content to the adapter, just to the spinner. But the last time i used a spinner dynamically i had to notify the spinnerAdapter

```
names.add("text");
spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: for me it add to the spinner without notifying the adapter tho. do u know why?? @Roman

Comment: therefore i need some code. where do you have initialized the spinner adapter. maybe your app inits the spinner adapter again or something like that